# What are the copper, silver and gold icons next to people's names?

Tags: support, user-interface

What is the use of the copper, silver and gold icons next to usernames?
Is there something on this site I can buy to pimp my account?

I'm kind of lost on this one, hope it's the right place to ask this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the number of bronze, silver and gold badges you've earned. No, you can't buy them. You earn them for participating in the site in various helpful ways.

Here's a [list of badges and how to get them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges) (that's the same link you get when click on the "Badges" button between "Users" and "Unanswered" on the top of the site).

Comment: Thanks, I just had no idea what their use was.
Guess I have played a little too much WoW lately.

Comment: @ninjaboi21 You get an Epic Mount [Ethereal Death Unicorn] at 1million rep. not really. :)